# Display rotated views that exceed screen bounds correctly without resizing

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Right now I am trying to solve a problem with adding views on top of a custom view that can exceed the screen bounds. That custom view draws different rectangles at different angles. For later use it should be possible to select the rectangles for later drag n drop implementations where I don’t want to constantly redraw the whole custom view.

So over each drawn rectangle I put a button that has the same dimensions and rotation.

For some reason however android seems to resize my views automatically when it hits the end of the Screen:

**My expectation(button covers everything even if only half visible):**

[image: Image: button covers everything even if only half visible]

**The actual behaviour(button gets shrunk):**

[image: Image: button gets shrunk]

This by itself is not a huge issue when the view I want to add is not rotated.

If the view is rotated however the rotation around the center point causes all kinds of problems as the view is now smaller and on a different location:

**My expectation(button is rotated exactly around the center point of the object):**

[image: Image: button is rotated exactly around the center point of the object]

**What I get is button becomes smaller and therefore its center point moves:**

[image: button becomes smaller and therefore its center point moves]

I read on other questions that View.setClipChildren(false) and View.setClipPadding(false) should help. But all it does is basically mess up my view hierarchy because I kinda want clipping to happen but not the automated resize. And on top of that it doesn’t fix the issue that I am having.

Does any of you have an Idea how I can fix this?

I tried to do the same on IOS and JavaFX which both work as I expected them to.

Since I am trying to solve the whole thing programmatically, I created some test code that places a buttons center point on the screen edge and rotates it 45 degrees: So you should only be able to see half of the button. But the button appears smaller and is fully visible on the right side of the screen. Of course due to the different center point it’s also not on the location I would expect it to be.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText("DO STUFF"); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(800, 80);
        params.leftMargin = width - 400; 
        params.topMargin = height / 2;

        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setRotation(45);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        relativeLayout.addView(button);

        setContentView(relativeLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself by accident.

It appears to be a special behavior of the RelativeLayout. I didn't find anything that explains it, but I swapped it out with a FrameLayout which has two positive effects.

1. It works as I expected it to
2. I got a performance increase since I was also nesting multiple Relative Layouts into each other.